# tf.data for keras model with multiple inputs, one ctc output, ValueError

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm using tf.version '2.1.0-rc2'

My model has 2 inputs and 1 output and I am struggling to feed it data.

Example https://keras.io/examples/image_ocr/ uses a generator that output 
a dictionary of numpy arrays.

```
inputs = {'the_input': X_data,
          'the_labels': labels,
          'input_length': input_length,
          'label_length': label_length,
          'source_str': source_str  # used for visualization only
          }
outputs = {'ctc': np.zeros([size])} 
return (inputs, outputs)
```

and fit_generator

```
   model.fit_generator(
        generator=img_gen.next_train(),
        steps_per_epoch=(words_per_epoch - val_words) // minibatch_size,
        epochs=stop_epoch,
        validation_data=img_gen.next_val(),
        validation_steps=val_words // minibatch_size,
        callbacks=[viz_cb, img_gen],
        initial_epoch=start_epoch)
```

but https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model indicates

> Warning: THIS FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed in a future
>   version. Instructions for updating: Please use Model.fit, which
>   supports generators.

I believe td.data is the recommended way to feed data into tf.keras.
So I would like to figure this out.

First, a simplified dummy model

```
def why_fail(input_size, one_hot_output_size, model_output_shape):
    ''' A dummy model, to focus on issue of multiple inputs '''

    a = Input(name="the_image_input", shape=(320, 128, 1))
    b = Input(name="the_book_id_input", shape=(20,))
    print(f"the_image_input.shape = {a.shape}, the_book_id_input.shape = {b.shape}")
    # the_image_input.shape = (None, 320, 128, 1), the_book_id_input.shape = (None, 20)

    c = Flatten()(a)
    d = Concatenate()([b, c]) # ([b, c])

    # reduce dimension to something we can make 40*xxx
    e = Dense(units=model_output_shape[1]*2)(d )
    f = Reshape( (model_output_shape[1],2) )(e)

    output_data = Dense(units=one_hot_output_size, activation="softmax")(f )

    print(f"into ctc output.shape = {output_data.shape}")
    # into ctc output.shape = (None, 40, 72)

    return Model(inputs=[a,b],  outputs=output_data)
```

My generator based on tf.data

```
def get_tf_dataset(height, width, batch_size, alphabet, record_limit = 10000000, partition_name="train", max_string_length=128, angle_in_radians=30/180*math.pi, min_percent_of_target=0.95, dataset=None, full_word_only=True, expensive_safety_checks=False, debug_dir_path=None, sample_output_path=None):

    # my data fits in memory (for now at least)
    my_data = read_dataset(alphabet, record_limit=record_limit, partition_names=[partition_name], max_string_length=max_string_length, expensive_safety_checks=expensive_safety_checks, debug_dir_path=debug_dir_path)

    def generator():
        i = 0
        while True:
            i = (i + 1) % len(my_data[partition_name]["image"])

            img = my_data[partition_name]["image"][i]
            img = kiss_image.phase_2_img_rnd_rot_rnd_size_rnd_position_rnd_noise(image=img, id=id, height=height, width=width, angle_in_radians=angle_in_radians, min_percent_of_target=min_percent_of_target, expensive_safety_checks=expensive_safety_checks, debug_dir_path=debug_dir_path )

            book_id = my_data[partition_name]["book_id"][i]
            text_as_alphabet_index = my_data[partition_name]["text_as_alphabet_index"][i]

            if len(text_as_alphabet_index) <= max_string_length:

                text_as_alphabet_index_array = pad_sequences([text_as_alphabet_index], maxlen=max_string_length, padding="post")
                text_as_alphabet_index_array = text_as_alphabet_index_array[0]

                print(f"the_image_input.shape = {img.shape}")
                print(f"the_book_id_input.shape = {book_id.shape}")
                print(f"text_as_alphabet_index_array.shape = {text_as_alphabet_index_array.shape}")

                # the_image_input.shape = (320, 128)
                # the_book_id_input.shape = (20,)
                # text_as_alphabet_index_array.shape = (18,)

                yield {"the_image_input": img, "the_book_id_input": book_id}, text_as_alphabet_index_array


    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, output_types=({"the_image_input": tf.float64, "the_book_id_input": tf.float64}, tf.int64))
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    return dataset
```

Instantiate a train and validation generator from the above

```
g_train = kiss_grabner.get_tf_dataset(partition_name="train", record_limit=1000*2*1, height=height, width=width, batch_size=batch_size, max_string_length=max_string_length, alphabet=alphabet, angle_in_radians=15/180*math.pi, full_word_only=full_word_only, min_percent_of_target=0.95, sample_output_path=sample_output_path)
g_valid = kiss_grabner.get_tf_dataset(partition_name="valid", record_limit=1000*2*1, height=height, width=width, batch_size=batch_size, max_string_length=max_string_length, alphabet=alphabet, angle_in_radians=15/180*math.pi, full_word_only=full_word_only, min_percent_of_target=0.95, sample_output_path=sample_output_path)
```

Call fit with the td.data generators

```
model.fit(  x= g_train, #generator.next_train_batch_with_book_id(),
            steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
            epochs=1000,
            validation_data=g_valid, #generator.next_valid_batch(), #validation_data=generator.next_valid_batch_with_book_id(),
            validation_steps=1000,
            callbacks=callbacks
        )
```

The error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kiss_run_model_on_grabner.py", line 371, in <module>
    callbacks=callbacks
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 819, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 235, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 593, in _process_training_inputs
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 706, in _process_inputs
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 702, in __init__
    x = standardize_function(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 684, in standardize_function
    return dataset.map(map_fn, num_parallel_calls=dataset_ops.AUTOTUNE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1591, in map
    self, map_func, num_parallel_calls, preserve_cardinality=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3926, in __init__
    use_legacy_function=use_legacy_function)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3147, in __init__
    self._function = wrapper_fn._get_concrete_function_internal()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 2395, in _get_concrete_function_internal
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 2389, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 2703, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 2593, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 978, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3140, in wrapper_fn
    ret = _wrapper_helper(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3082, in _wrapper_helper
    ret = autograph.tf_convert(func, ag_ctx)(*nested_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in converted code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py:677 map_fn
        batch_size=None)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py:2410 _standardize_tensors
        exception_prefix='input')
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py:526 standardize_input_data
        standardize_single_array(x, shape) for (x, shape) in zip(data, shapes)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py:526 <listcomp>
        standardize_single_array(x, shape) for (x, shape) in zip(data, shapes)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py:451 standardize_single_array
        if (x.shape is not None and len(x.shape) == 1 and
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:822 __len__
        raise ValueError("Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank.")

    ValueError: Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank.
```

I also tried the dictionary approach

```
 def next_train_batch_with_book_id(self):

train = self.dataset["train"]
while True:
    xy = self.get_batch(train, return_ids_and_text_too=True, angle_in_radians=self.angle_in_radians, min_percent_of_target=self.min_percent_of_target, full_word_only=self.full_word_only)

    an_array_of_images = xy["image"]
    an_array_of_book_ids = xy["book_id"]
    an_array_of_1_hot  = xy["text_as_alphabet_index"]

    print(f"an_array_of_images.shape = {an_array_of_images.shape}")
    print(f"an_array_of_book_ids.shape = {an_array_of_book_ids.shape}")
    print(f"an_array_of_1_hot.shape = {an_array_of_1_hot.shape}")
    # an_array_of_images.shape = (32, 320, 128, 1)
    # an_array_of_book_ids.shape = (32, 20)
    #an_array_of_1_hot.shape = (32, 18)

    # dictionary based input/output to model
    inputs  = { 'the_image_input': an_array_of_images, "the_book_id_input": an_array_of_book_ids} 
    outputs = { 'the_text_as_alphabet_index_input' : an_array_of_1_hot }

    # just the data as input
    #inputs = an_array_of_images 
    outputs =  an_array_of_1_hot 

    xy = (inputs, outputs, [])

    yield xy
```

...

with model.fit calling as recommended

```
model.fit(  x=generator.next_train_batch_with_book_id(),
            steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
            epochs=1000,
            validation_data=generator.next_valid_batch(), #validation_data=generator.next_valid_batch_with_book_id(),
            validation_steps=1000,
            callbacks=callbacks
        )
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kiss_run_model_on_grabner.py", line 371, in <module>
    callbacks=callbacks
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 819, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 235, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 614, in _process_training_inputs
    distribution_strategy=distribution_strategy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 706, in _process_inputs
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 767, in __init__
    dataset = standardize_function(dataset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py", line 684, in standardize_function
    return dataset.map(map_fn, num_parallel_calls=dataset_ops.AUTOTUNE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1591, in map
    self, map_func, num_parallel_calls, preserve_cardinality=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3926, in __init__
    use_legacy_function=use_legacy_function)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3147, in __init__
    self._function = wrapper_fn._get_concrete_function_internal()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 2395, in _get_concrete_function_internal
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 2389, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 2703, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 2593, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 978, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3140, in wrapper_fn
    ret = _wrapper_helper(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3082, in _wrapper_helper
    ret = autograph.tf_convert(func, ag_ctx)(*nested_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in converted code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py:677 map_fn
        batch_size=None)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py:2410 _standardize_tensors
        exception_prefix='input')
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py:539 standardize_input_data
        str(data)[:200] + '...')

    ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), for inputs ['the_image_input', 'the_book_id_input'] but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [<tf.Tensor 'args_0:0' shape=(None, None, None, None) dtype=float32>]...
```

Comment: `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` has an optional `output_shapes` parameter. Omitting the parameter could be causing the shape to be unknown, eventually leading to the "ValueError: Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank" error.